# Expo React Native iOS 15 problems

Tags: react-native, expo

Is there any way to build with Expos service `eas` with XCode 13. We need to support iOS 15 as soon as possible.

Thank you for your help.

With that configuration, it only builds with XCode Version 12.5.

eas.json

```json
{
  "build": {
    "release": {},
    "preview": {
      "ios": {
        "image": "latest",
        "distribution": "internal"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on this problem myself

A first step could be using the latest ios image like this:

```
  "ios": {
    "image": "macos-big-sur-11.4-xcode-13.0"
  },
```

Sauce : https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/infrastructure/#image--macos-big-sur-114-xcode-130

Edit: It worked for me with this config (latest versions of fastlane and cocoapods)

```
  "ios": {
    "image": "macos-big-sur-11.4-xcode-13.0",
    "fastlane": "2.195.0",
    "cocoapods": "1.11.2"
  },
```